# How do I stop this program from calling a non-existant list element?

Tags: python, list

```
import string

## This part of the code initializes the program by recieving inputs and saving
## them as strings.
## It also currently works!

intext = str.lower(raw_input("Please input the text you are going to use. "))
##print intext
instring = str.lower(raw_input("Please input your string. "))
##print instring
inlengthminus = int(raw_input("Please input the number of words you would like before the matched word. ONLY PUT AN INTEGER HERE!"))
inlengthplus = int(raw_input("Please input the number of words you would like after the matched word. ONLY PUT AN INTEGER HERE!"))
## This part of the code splits the text into searchable lists.
## It only works when the cases match, which is why the search lists
## convert the text to lowercase.

searchtext=str.split(intext)
##print searchtext
searchstring=list(instring+1)
##print searchstring

## This is the actual search process.
## It works, mostly.

length = len(searchtext)
stringlength = len(searchstring)
##print stringlength

x=0
for a in range(0,length):
    print a
    print searchstring[x]
    print x
    if searchstring[x] in searchtext[a]:
        if (a-inlengthminus)<0:
            print "You almost caused an error, please pick a number of words before your matched word that won't call text that doesn't exist."
            break
        else:
            print searchtext[a-inlengthminus:a+inlengthplus+1]    
            x+=1
    else:
        pass
```

I don't know how to stop this program from calling a value for searchstring[x] that is greater than the length of searchstring. Is there a way to stop x from causing this overflow error?

Comment: What do you want to do when `x` passes the length of `searchstring`?

Comment: What is this code doing? What kind of input/output are you looking for here?

Comment: It's a mesostic generator. This program takes an input text (such as a novel or news report) and an input string (like the name John Cage) and then runs through the text grabbing words that contain the letters, in order, in the input string. I want to reset x to 0 when it gets past the last letter in the input string, so that the program continues to run until the length of the text has been traversed. Thank you for helping me clarify my question, too.

Comment: This is obviously not the whole code, since it won't work as-is. Maybe you can add more of it? Also an explanation of what the overall goal, or task is here.

Comment: Sure I reposted it with the whole module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
x+=1
```

With

```
x = (x + 1) % len(searchstring)
```

The modulus operator does division and returns the remainder.  So x from 0 up to the length of searchstring, the modulus does nothing (returns itself).  If x == the length of searchstring, it "resets" to 0, because there is no remainder when dividing.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for helping out a complete novice.

Comment: @alex you should probably consider using regular expressions, and the `re` module.